# How to create a web portal using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Im fresh out of the academy and have been given my first project. I need to create a web portal that can interface with RESTFUL services. Can anyone advise me on where and how to start?

After I create the basic html and css Web page I have to integrate the CRUD module. Should I look at creating a single page application?

Any advise is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic here. You can find plenty of tutorials on how to build a web application on google.

Answer (score 1):

As Matus Dubrava as mentioned, this is off-topic and a very broad question. But I can help you with some guideline -

You will be having a database (mysql, postgresql, mongo etc.), an API server (can be built with Java Spring Boot, Python Django, NodeJS, PHP etc.) and lastly a frontend application (can be built with angularjs, reactjs etc.).

First, you have to sort out what you already know among these and then plan ahead what other modules you need to learn. After deciding what technologies you will use, you can google the tutorials and sample code for that technology. If I can help more ask me out.

Hope this helps.